# Get resource file from dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, jar, resources, sbt, sbt-web

I have a [sbt-web](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web) project with some webjar and common jar dependencies. I want to get resource file from one of my jar dependency and use it in [concatenation](https://github.com/ground5hark/sbt-concat#sbt-concat) task. But I don't know how refer to the resource inside dependent jar in my build.sbt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally find the solution with [this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Classpaths.html) docs. The main idea is to find the right jar in the classpath dependencies, unzip it to temprorary folder and do what you need with this files. In my case I copy it to my target directory and use it in concatenation task.

I end up with this code:

```
def copyResourceFromJar(classpathEntry: Attributed[File], jarName: String, resourceName: String) = {
  classpathEntry.get(artifact.key) match {
    case Some(entryArtifact) => {
      // searching artifact
      if (entryArtifact.name.startsWith(jarName)) {
        // unpack artifact's jar to tmp directory
        val jarFile = classpathEntry.data
        IO.withTemporaryDirectory { tmpDir =>
          IO.unzip(jarFile, tmpDir)
          // copy to project's target directory
          // Instead of copying you can do any other stuff here 
          IO.copyFile(
            tmpDir / resourceName,
            (WebKeys.webJarsDirectory in Assets).value / resourceName
          )
        }
      }
    }
    case _ =>
  }
}
for(entry <- (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value) yield {
  copyResourceFromJar(entry, "firstJar", "firstFile.js")
  copyResourceFromJar(entry, "secondJar", "some/path/secondFile.js")
}
```

This code should be placed in the task. For example:

```
val copyResourcesFromJar = TaskKey[Unit]("copyResourcesFromJar", "Copy resources from jar dependencies")
copyResourcesFromJar := {
  //your task code here
}
copyResourcesFromJar <<= copyResourcesFromJar dependsOn (dependencyClasspath in Compile)
```

And don't forget to add this task as dependcy to your build task. In my case it looks like this:

```
concat <<= concat dependsOn copyResourcesFromJar
```

Comment: I used this solution to get liquibase changesets which was in parent project. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The other answers didn't work for me, I think because they're on older versions of SBT. I've been banging my head against this for a while but I finally got something to work. Here's the full script that will do this resource copying before an arbitrary Compile task (mine is `guardrail`) on SBT v1.5.5:

```scala
lazy val myDep = "my-dep-project"
lazy val myFilename = "someDir/myFile.yaml"

val copyResourcesFromJars =
  TaskKey[Unit]("copyResourcesFromJars", "Copy specific resources to be used by this project")

copyResourcesFromJars := {
  def copyResourceFromJar(classpathEntry: Attributed[File], jarName: String, resourceName: String): Unit = {
    classpathEntry.get(artifact.key) match {
      case Some(entryArtifact) =>
        // searching artifact
        if (entryArtifact.name.startsWith(jarName)) {
          // unpack artifact's jar to tmp directory
          val jarFile = classpathEntry.data
          IO.withTemporaryDirectory { tmpDir =>
            IO.unzip(jarFile, tmpDir)
            // copy to project's target directory
            // Instead of copying you can do any other stuff here
            IO.copyFile(
              tmpDir / resourceName,
              baseDirectory.value / s"target/$resourceName"
            )
          }
        }
      case _ =>
    }
  }

  (Compile / dependencyClasspath).value.foreach(entry =>
    copyResourceFromJar(entry, myDep, myFilename)
  )
}

Compile / guardrail := (Compile / guardrail dependsOn copyResourcesFromJars).value

(project in file(".")).settings(
  ...
  Compile / guardrailTasks := List(
    ScalaServer(
      baseDirectory.value / s"target/$myFilename",
      pkg = "my.pkg.guardrail"
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally **getResourceAsStream** works:

```
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/resource/in/jar")
```

It is important to read the resource as a Stream *getClass.getResource* will not work.